# Multiplexing two Bluetooth devices to create dual audio

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth

We want to tackle the age old question of connecting two musicboxes over bluetooth and stream music on them simultaneously. 
We know, that modern smartphones are able to connect to two devices but the output audio stream only connects to one device. And according to a lot of different sources the A2DP Profile is also only able to have one Master and one Slave.

Our approach would be a multiplexing of the said audio output between the two connected devices. So on android we would just have to change the desired audio output fast enough between two boxes.

The first question here would be if the switching between two audio outputs on android is fast enough and the music doesnt stop streaming? 
Secondly we have to determine if the switching can happen fast enough for us to dont hear any skips.